# how include external library in c++ with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I got my directory like:

```
-lib
-- mylibrary.dll
-- mylibrary.lib
-- mylibrary.exp
-main.cpp
-cmakelist
```

and i want my cmake to include the library into the main project like following:

```
link_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
add_executable(test_app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testapp mylibrary)
```

but the the include do not find the header. I tried find_package but that did not work...

anyone can help me?

Comment: it does not find the header because you need all the header files for your library to be in the `lib` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) to point CMake to your header search folders.

> Add the given directories to those the compiler uses to search for include files. Relative paths are interpreted as relative to the current source directory.

Comment: I dont have any header files, are they not in the lib?

Comment: @mstranne no, they are not. in C/C++, there are two parts to a library, the library and the headers which include all library method declarations.

Comment: I'd recommend `target_include_directories` instead of `include_directories`.  See [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eC9-iRN2b04) for best practices of modular CMake build.